# How do I capture a MySQL result set in a bash array?

Tags: bash, shell-script, mysql, variable, array

I'm using bash shell on CentOS 7.  I want to run a MySQL query from a shell script and iterate over each row of results.  If there were 4 rows returned, I thought I could capture the four rows in an array like so:

```
query="select p.id, p.ebook_id, es.id FROM ...";
echo "$query" > /tmp/query.sql
mysql -u user --password=pass db_id < /tmp/query.sql > /tmp/query.csv

linesIN=`cat /tmp/query.csv | sed 's/\t/,/g'`
arraylength=${#linesIN[@]}
echo $arraylength
```

However, `$arraylength` always outputs `1` even though I can see multiple result rows returned.  How can I modify the above to correctly create an array of results where each element in the array represents one row from the result set?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not using `--batch` for your `mysql` invocation?  That's what it's there for.

Comment: My advice is to just not use bash. Use a proper scripting language.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With the [`--batch` option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_batch), `mysql` should output the result one record on a line, and columns separated by tabs. You can read the lines to an array with [Bash's `mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-mapfile) and process substitution, or command substitution and array assignment:

```
mapfile results  < <( mysql --batch ... < query.sql )
```

or

```
set -f        # disable globbing
IFS=$'\n'     # set field separator to NL (only)
results=( $(mysql --batch ... ) )
```

(Note that `IFS` stays modified and globbing disabled after this.)

Then, if you want to split the columns of a row to some variables:

```
IFS=$'\t' read -r col1 col2 col2 ... <<< "${results[0]}"
```

---

Your assignment

```
linesIN=`cat /tmp/query.csv | sed 's/\t/,/g'`
```

is not an [array assignment](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) (it's missing the parenthesis). It just assigns the output of the command substitution to a regular string variable. (Any newlines will be embedded there, but it'll still be a single string.) `${#linesIN[@]}` still works since in Bash/ksh single-element arrays and scalar variables act the same.

Comment: So there is no way to do this with 2+ lines returned from MySQL?

Comment: What is in results?

Comment: @Dims, with `mapfile results < <(foo)`, whatever the command `foo` printed, split to one line per array element. The second snippet would do pretty much the same.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to do it would be to pipe the output of the command to a  while loop. Note you want to include the -N or the results include the column name.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script to read output from a mysql command line by line 

mysql -uroot -p example -N -e "select column from table" | while IFS= read -r loop
do
    echo "$loop"
done
```

And if you just want a count, you'd do a `select count(columnName)` and print out the results.

Comment: If one wishes to use the results elsewhere, they are not accessible outside the `while`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the number of lines in a file, which will be equal to the number of rows returned from query, just use `wc` to count number of lines in the file

```
  arraylength=$( wc -l < /tmp/query.csv)
  echo $arraylength
```

Comment: Using redirection `wc -l </tmp/query.csv` avoids the need to remove the filename

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i updated my answer